# What is uniform distribution and its use in our daily life?

Tags: probability

[image]
Uniform distribution: the density function of a continuous r.v. X is called a uniform distribution when between the end points any two subintervals of the same length containing X, have the same probability.

Answer (score 1):

The definition you gave pretty much explains it. A simple example would be this:

Consider a wire of length 1 metre, where a=0 and b=1. Now say you cut the wire at a random point anywhere between 0 and 1. The probability that the wire is cut in the first half of the wire is:

$$\dfrac{0.5}{1}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

where 0.5 is the length from the start of the wire up till the middle of the wire.
Similarly, say I want to find the probability that the wire is cut from 0.25m up till 0.75m, then the probability would be:
$$\dfrac{0.75-0.25}{1}=\dfrac{0.5}{1}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$
As you can see, the two probabilities are the same, regardless of where the 0.5m interval is taken....due to being uniformly distributed. Any two intervals of the same length have the same probability.